# when I convert a graphis to an image I got black one

Tags: java, image, graphics

I am trying to convert a graphics to image to insert it into a Word document but I got black image this is my code :

```
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
Graphics g2 = jPanel2.getGraphics();
Drawer drawer = new Drawer();
drawer.setSource(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
drawer.paintComponent(g2);
jPanel2.print(g2);

BufferedImage awtImage = new BufferedImage(900, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
g2 = awtImage.getGraphics();
SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g2, jPanel2, this, 0, 0,
jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight());

ImageIO.write(awtImage, "jpg", new File("C:\\graphics.jpg"));
```

The class `Drawer` is responsible of the graphics (drawing the graphics)
Would you help me to find the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if this approach would work. Java's `Robot` class can be used to make a screenshot of whatever is displayed on the screen. Make the panel displayed and than capture it: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0489.html

Comment: @BorisPavlović Why would he want a screenshot?  It looks like to me he wants to enter a filepath in a text field and convert that image (not sure why, but thats what it looks like hes doing)

Comment: I am trying to enter an XML file as input and generate graphics from information in this XML file then I would like to convert this graphics to an image to insert it in a word document but when I try to convert graphics to an image I get black one

Comment: @jiji Are you sure the drawer class is working as intended?  Sounds like the file generation from XML could be buggy or something. We cant tell without seeing any of it.

Comment: to many calls not clear what they do, and looks more like conflict, `drawer.paintComponent(g2);` `jPanel2.print(g2);` `g2 = awtImage.getGraphics();` and more, looks like code was gathered from different sources which meant different purposes. i suggest you to make a clean code, no need for the jpanel, just create a buffered image, get the graphics from image and draw, then save the image to disk

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks the class drawer works fine and generate correctly the graphics

Comment: @jiji How do you know?

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks I used the same class Drawer to show to the user the graphics after entring the XML file  and it shows correctly the different parts of the graphics